wkhtmltopdf: runs js if I pass it a page url but not from a static html file
I'm using a native javascript plugin to highlight some text in a web page.
If I pass wkhtmltopdf the url of the page then the highlighting comes through in the resulting pdf.
However, if I render out the page to an html file first, and then pass that html file to wk, then it doesn't run the js and I don't get the highlighting.
Is there a way around this?  I could run it again against the url, but it would mean a double-request to the website which isn't very efficient.
My version is
 wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt)
This is the js I have in my html:
      <script src="/javascripts/mark_highlighter/dist/mark.js"/>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

          var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector(".doc__page"));
          //can take an array of strings or a single string
          instance.mark(<%= params[:highlighted].inspect %>, {
            separateWordSearch: false
            ,accuracy: "exactly"
          });
        });
      </script>


How are you embedding the relevant script(s)? This is really lacking any useful detail so far, but my first guess would be that it probably has problems loading the scripts via relative URLs, that can't be resolved correctly in the "pass an HTML file" context.

@CBroe ah yes, i think you might be right...  I will try making the js load from a local filepath or an external url...

@CBroe yep, changing to an external url for the script tag's src fixed it.  If you feel like writing an answer then i'll mark it correct.  I'll add a bit more detail to my question.  thanks!

Your first <script> tag is invalid. You attempt to close the element by putting  a slash in <script /> but this tag always requires a closing </script>

With the scripts being embedded using relative URLs, wkhtmltopdf is likely to have problems "finding" them, in the context of an HTML document being passed.
/javascripts/mark_highlighter/dist/mark.js is probably taken as a path from the file system root (at least on a Linux system) - but the files are likely not located there. In the HTTP context, this maps to the document root instead.

Thanks - I fixed it by changing the mark.js script tag src attribute to src="https://mywebsite.com/javascripts/mark_highlighter/dist/mark.js"
